# Adding button style to AppTheme not working

Tags: android, button, styles, themes

I've tried to add a custom button style to my AppTheme and it is not working.  As a reference, I've added a Spinner style to my AppTheme and it works fine.  So, I just need to find out where I'm going wrong with my button style.

style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/mySpinnerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/myButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/myButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="mySpinnerStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="overlapAnchor">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5sp</item>
</style>

<style name="myButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_states</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

I can add my button_states.xml file if needed, but know that the style works if I insert my style directly to a button attribute in my layout like below:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    style="@style/myButtonStyle"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
    android:text="OK" />
```

Declaration in Parent layout:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

So, why does it work directly in the button attribute but not through my AppTheme?

Comment: The parent of the themes doesn't need a @style. And try to leave the app theme in the manifest, easier to manage

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I applied your suggestions and things are working now.  Removing the @style from the parent on the "myButtonStyle" made it work.  Though the style changes don't show in the preview in the IDE, it only shows when running the app.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ahmad Sattout for the answer.

In my button style I removed the @style from the parent:

original:

```
<style name="myButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_states</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

changed:

```
<style name="myButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_states</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

If anyone can explain in further detail why that happens, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's just a wrong compilation. Styles tend to tell you nothing about what is wrong or what's not right. You added the @style but the studio doesn't know if that's right or wrong

Answer (score 0):

1- Create new DRAWABLE RESOUCE FILE by right click on res / drawable file in your android studio

2- write code like this in it :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
android:radius="100dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF"

        />
    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp"
        />

</shape>
```

3- open your XML file which contain this button and change background of button to the drawable you created before

Comment: Thanks, yes I have a similar file for my buttons.  I didn't show that file because I knew the error was somewhere in the code that I did show.